# Having problems with a Lambda LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to convert the following SQL expression into a Lambda LINQ query and I seem to be going round in circles at the moment:

```
select m.MemberExternalPK FROM Member.Member AS m INNER JOIN Member.Account AS a ON m.MemberID = a.MemberID where m.MemberExternalPK in 
(
    SELECT m.MemberExternalPK
    FROM Member.Member AS m INNER JOIN Member.Account AS a ON m.MemberID = a.MemberID
    group by MemberExternalPK
    having Count(AccountID) = 1 
)
and AccountStatusID = 3
```

So far I have managed to get the following syntax that returns the correct number of rows I am after but all columns (except the MemberExternalPK one I want)!

```
Members.Join(Accounts, m => m.MemberID, a => a.MemberID, (m, a) => new { m, a })
    .GroupBy(t => t.m.MemberExternalPK, t => t.a)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count(p => p.AccountID != null) == 1)
    .SelectMany(sublist => sublist).Where(x => x.AccountStatusID == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fairly close:

```
var query =
    from m in Member_Member
    join a in Member_Account on m.MemberID equals a.MemberID
    group a by m.MemberExternalPK into gas
    where gas.Count(ga => ga.AccountID != null) == 1
    from ga in gas
    where ga.AccountStatusID == 3
    select gas.Key;
```

The only concern is the `ga.AccountID != null` which means that the `gas` group may have more than one record so you might end up with more than one `gas.Key` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Splitting it up could also improve performance.

```
var externalMembers = 
    Members.Join(Accounts, m => m.MemberID, a => a.MemberID, (m, a) => new { m, a })
           .GroupBy(grp => grp.MemberExternalPK)
           .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
           .Select(grp => grp.Key);

var result = 
    Members.Where(w => externalMembers.Contains(w.MemberExternalPK) && w.AccountStatusID == 3)
           .Select(s => s.MemberExternalPK)
```